# Need help with putting Cygwin on DVD for a offline install

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to put the whole of [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) on a DVD, so I can have it with me for an offline install. I downloaded `setup.exe`, putted "download without install" and selected *Current version* and under "All" I selected "Install".

After it downloaded all of it, I burned it onto a DVD.

Now when I try to install the thing, it reports some missing dependencies and gives out a lot (and I do mean A LOT) of <NULL> errors.

Where did I go wrong? I'm assuming what I'm trying to do (put it on a DVD) is possible using that technnique?

Comment: If my memory serves me right: I think this question has now been changed. It appears as if we (Joshua Nurczyk and undersigned) don't answer the question, but we did at the time (just instructions for offline install). (I will do some research and delete this comment if it turns out not to be the case).

Answer (score 2):

From the Cygwin web site:

How can I make my own portable Cygwin on CD?

While some users have successfully done this, for example Indiana University's XLiveCD http://xlivecd.indiana.edu/, there is no easy way to do it. Full instructions for constructing a porttable Cygwin on CD by hand can be found on the mailing list at http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2003-07/msg01117.html. (Thanks to fergus at bonhard dot uklinux dot net for these instructions.)

Comment: As far as I see, they're trying to make portable cygwin that runs from a cd. I'm just trying to copy the installation to cd so I don't have to download it every time.

Comment: Ah, obviously I didn't research too much, sorry... Maybe use those instructions then copy from the DVD and don't have to install it? Not the best / most optimum, and not what you're asking for, I know.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered over at Stack Overflow: "[Where can I download an offline installer of Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661939/where-can-i-download-an-offline-installer-of-cygwin/662415#662415)".

Look for the answer starting with "Here are instructions
assuming you want to install Cygwin on a computer with no
Internet connection."

(Perhaps that entry should be moved over to Server Fault?)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try the ['pmcyg'](http://pmcyg.sourceforge.net) tool.

This will download all the packages you choose, together with their dependencies and the setup.exe. You can also get pmcyg to download all available Cygwin packages, optionally with source-code.

The resulting collection of files can then be burned onto a DVD or CDROM to be used as a completely self-contained offline installer.

Comment: +1 I've never heard this great python tool before.